# ElasticSearch nesting Must and Should

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying create some filters for a web application. Users need to be able to filter by users (checkboxes) and by types (also checkboxes).

I need something like this (in T-SQL) to Elasticsearch :

```
SELECT * from documents d
WHERE (
    d.user = 'user1' OR
    d.user = 'user2'
) AND (
    d.type = 'type1ID' OR 
    d.type = 'type2ID'
)
```

Comment: I've added an answer for you. Hope it'll work for you ")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested but You need something like this,

with `term`,

```
GET documents/_search
{
   "query" : {
      "constant_score" : { 
         "filter" : {
            "bool" : {
              "should" : [
                 { "term" : {"user" : "user1"}}, 
                 { "term" : {"user" : "user2"}} 
              ],
              "should" : {
                 { "term" : {"type" : "type1ID"}},
                 { "term" : {"type" : "type2ID"}}
              }
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

OR with `terms`

```
GET documents/_search
{
     "query" : {
        "constant_score" : { 
           "filter" : {
              "bool" : {
                 "should" : [
                    {"terms": {"user": ["user1","user2"]}}
                  ],
                 "should" : {
                    {"terms": {"type": ["type1ID","type2ID"]}}
                 }
              }
            }
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to combine both must and should clauses to achieve what your looking for:

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{ 
         "must":{
            "match_all":{}
         },
         "filter":{
            "bool":{
               "must":[
                  {
                     "bool":{
                        "should":[
                           {
                              "term":{
                                 "user":"user1"
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "term":{
                                 "user":"user2"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "bool":{
                        "should":[
                           {
                              "term":{
                                 "type":"type1ID"
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "term":{
                                 "type":"type2ID"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In this example, the filter applies to the match_all clause which is your 'SELECT *'.The first level 'must'acts like the 'AND' and both second level 'should' are acting like your 'OR'.